# ClosableHttpClient - getting Exception "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE"

Tags: java, http

I am working on a small browser implementation in Java.

I'm using Apache HttpComponents 4.3.1, because it has an automatic forward mechanism, but I am having trouble figuring out how it really works.

From the Apache docs [Chapter 1. Fundamentals](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/), I am trying to use this code excerpt:

```
LaxRedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new LaxRedirectStrategy();
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setRedirectStrategy(redirectStrategy)
        .build();
```

This should create a `ClosableHttpClient` which can use automatically forward. But on the 2nd line (where the client is created by calling `.build()`) I get this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   INSTANCE  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>
>   (DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:52)

There is not more code, i just call this code snippet via:

```
HttpClient myClient = createClient();
```

It makes no difference if I am using explicit:

```
ClosableHttpClient myClient = createClient();
```

*(which I found in the [Apache Tutorial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e321))*

I suspect that some library is interfering, so here is my classpath overview:

[image: My Classpath]

Comment: I figured it out by myself:

Using http client 4.3.1 with the selenium version 2.35 trigger this error - i had to remove it and the depending classe. fortunately it the minibrowser isn't depending on selenium.

Greetings, hoping this helps some other who got trouble with it.

Comment: @Tony_B can you add your answer as an official answer, not just as a comment?

Comment: how did you find that conflict? I have the same problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760659/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance) Could you please help me to find the problem? @TonyB